# displaying image and list inline bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

okay. so I've got an image that has an un-ordered list that links to the image on its' left.
The main to its' left uses imagemapster.

It works so that if a list items gets clicked the corresponding info display on the right. That works no problem at all.

The problem I'm having however is that the list is being displayed to the bottom of the image.

I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class="img_beef row col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img class="beef_img img-responsive" id="beef_cut" src="images/beef.png" width="138px" height="357px" usemap="#imageMap" >
          <div class="cut_list col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <p>List of cuts</p>
              <ol>
                <li><a item="chuck_li" href="">Chuck , Hump</a></li>
                <li><a item="neck_li" href="">Neck</a></li>
                <li><a item="shin_li" href="">Shin</a></li>
                <li><a item="bolo_li" href="">Bolo</a></li>
                <li><a item="brisket_li" href="">Brisket</a></li>
                <li><a item="brisket01_li" href="">Brisket</a></li>
                <li><a item="flat_rib_li" href="">Flat Rib</a></li>
                <li><a item="prime_rib_li" href="">Prime Rib</a></li>
                <li><a item="short_rib_li" href="">Short Ribs</a></li>
                <li><a item="sirloin_li" href="">Sirloin</a></li>
                <li><a item="thin_flank_li" href="">Thin Flank</a></li>
                <li><a item="fillet_li" href="">Fillet</a></li>
                <li><a item="striploin_li" href="">Striploin</a></li>
                <li><a item="rump_li" href="">Rump</a></li>
                <li><a item="thick_flank_li" href="">Thick Flank</a></li>
                <li><a item="rump_li" href="">Rump</a></li>
                <li><a item="silver_li" href="">Silverside , Topside</a></li>
                <li><a item="shin_li" href="">Shin</a></li>
              </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Even with the col-lg-5 in the cut_list div it still does the same thing.

```
.img_beef {
border-right:solid thin #dbdbdb;
margin-right: 70px;
z-index:1000;
}

.img_beef img {
}


.hidden-phone >.img_beef> border-right {
    display:none;
}

.cut_list {
    float:right;
}

.cut_list p {
}

.img_beef ol {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777777;
    font-size:10px;
}

.img_beef a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777777;
}

.img_beef a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777777;
}
```

If any other info is needed, please let me know. I really need help with this one.

Comment: can you give a fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is no `row` for your nested columns. Also, if you're using nested columns you should put the list as well as the image inside a column.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/bQZHDnNFgc

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="img_beef col-lg-5 col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8">
        <img class="beef_img img-responsive" id="beef_cut" src="images/beef.png" usemap="#imageMap" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-4">
        <p>List of cuts</p>
        <ol>
          <li><a item="chuck_li" href="">Chuck , Hump</a></li>
          <li><a item="neck_li" href="">Neck</a></li>
          <li><a item="shin_li" href="">Shin</a></li>
          <li><a item="bolo_li" href="">Bolo</a></li>
          <li><a item="brisket_li" href="">Brisket</a></li>
          <li><a item="brisket01_li" href="">Brisket</a></li>
          <li><a item="flat_rib_li" href="">Flat Rib</a></li>
          <li><a item="prime_rib_li" href="">Prime Rib</a></li>
          <li><a item="short_rib_li" href="">Short Ribs</a></li>
          <li><a item="sirloin_li" href="">Sirloin</a></li>
          <li><a item="thin_flank_li" href="">Thin Flank</a></li>
          <li><a item="fillet_li" href="">Fillet</a></li>
          <li><a item="striploin_li" href="">Striploin</a></li>
          <li><a item="rump_li" href="">Rump</a></li>
          <li><a item="thick_flank_li" href="">Thick Flank</a></li>
          <li><a item="rump_li" href="">Rump</a></li>
          <li><a item="silver_li" href="">Silverside , Topside</a></li>
          <li><a item="shin_li" href="">Shin</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine, Much appreciated. I had to move a couple of elements in to the div that affected the image and list. All I need to do know is to work on responsiveness.But thanks @ChaoticNardis